# Post pdf to api (python) returns response with wrong encoding

Tags: python, api, python-requests, ocr

I am trying to use an ocr API with python to convert pdf to text. The API i'm using is : https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-txt . When i upload the file through the website it works perfectly but the API call has the following issue:

Python code:

```
import requests

url ='https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/pdf/to/txt?Secret=mykey'
files = {'file': open('C:\<some_url>\filename.pdf', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

The API call works fine, but it when i try to access the response through

```
r.text
```

it returns giberish: (Notice the FileData section)

```
'{"ConversionCost":4,"Files":[{"FileName":"stateoftheartKWextraction.txt","FileExt":"txt","FileSize":60179,"FileData":"QXV0b21hdGljIEtleXBocmFzZSBFeHRyYWN0aW9uOiBBIFN1cnZleSBvZiB0aGUgU3RhdGUgb2YgdGhlIEFydA0KDQpLYXppIFNhaWR1bCBIYXNhbiAgYW5kICBWaW5jZW50IE5nDQpIdW1hbiBMYW5ndWFnZSBUZWNobm9sb2d5IFJlc2VhcmNoIEluc3RpdHV0ZSBVbml2ZXJzaXR5IG9mIFRleGFzIGF0IERhbGxhcyBSaWNoYXJkc29uLCBUWCA3NTA4My0wNjg4DQp7c2FpZHVsLHZpbmNlfUBobHQudXRkYWxsYXMuZW...
```

Even if i use json load to convert it into a dict, it still prints the text in giberish.
I've tried to upload the file as not binary but that doesn't work(it throws an exception).

I've tried many pdf files and they all were in english.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The text is decoded, so you need to decode it. Let's take the first file as an example.

```
import base64

r = r.json()
text = r['Files'][0]['FileData']

print(base64.b64decode(text))
```

By the way, they seem to have a Python library as well, you might want to check that out: https://github.com/ConvertAPI/convertapi-python